# python interpreter not found for Django project after re-installing python

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have made an application using Django in pycharmIDE.after completing my project I deleted python from my machine and re-installed now when I run my application it shows

```
No Python at 'C:\Users\Raisan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe'
```

how can I set python interpreter in Pycharm

Comment: Please make sure if you have provided python path in PATH environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to set Python interpreter in a PyCharm project, you should click on:

```
File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter
```

Then, on the top of the window, you should have a dropdown selection with *Project Interpreter* label. Here you can choose the project interpreter for your project.

If the interpreter is not present, click on the settings icon (gear wheel) on the right anc choose "Add". 
Then choose "Existing enviroment" and navigate througth your directories until you will find your Interpreter. 
Remember that you have to select the python.exe file.

Answer (score 0):

Please set environment variable and try it  otherwise uninstall python and and reinstall it but that time select custom python install and choose appropriate options  like IDEdevelopment environment pip etc.